# Currently have a code to generate a bingo card and I want to figure out how to make a code to input a called number and blank out a space

Tags: python

```
import random

random_draw_list = random.sample(range(1, 76), 75)

def generate_card(): #Function to generate the bingo card
    """
    Generates a bingo card and stores the numbers in a dictionary.
    """
    card = {
        "B": [],
        "I": [],
        "N": [],
        "G": [],
        "O": [],
    } # The matrix of numbers with their coressponding letters
    min = 1
    max = 15 #initial range of values for B
    for letter in card:
        card[letter] = random.sample(range(min, max), 5) #Defines the range for each letter
        min += 15
        max += 15 #For each increment letter, the min and max of the range are increase by 15 to correspond the values to the right letters
        if letter == "N":
            card[letter][2] = "X" # This portion of the code defines the free space in the center of the board, basically says at (3,3) the person automatically gets a mark
    return card # This returns the card

def print_card(card): #function to print out the bingo card
    """
    Prints the bingo card.

    Arguments:
        card (dictionary): The card to be printed out.
    """
    for letter in card: #this segment defines what and how the card should be printed
        print(letter, end="\t")
        for number in card[letter]:
            print(number, end="\t")
        print("\n")
    print("\n")

def main(): #The initiating step so that when you run the program is run the card is generated
    """
    Main method for the program. Generates a card, prints it, and loops through drawing
    and printing until the check_win method returns True or the user enters "quit".
    """
    print("Let's play bingo!")
    card = generate_card()

    print("\nHere is your card:\n")
    print_card(card)
main()
```

Comment: just use `input()` Also, please don't use `min`, `max` or similar variable names, as these are already used for functions, and it could cause your program to behave in a weird way.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.